# The file could not be saved Drupal

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

uploading images from desktop is fine but the problem is when i need to upload image from 
mobile browser give me that error

- the file 14343254.jpg could not be saved . an unknown error has occurred
- the file in the Photo field was unable to be uploaded
- photo field is required

Answer (score -1, accepted):

i finally solved my problem after 1 week of searching

The problem is  i am using aws ec2 server with 8GB volume and its 70% filled so images from mobile camera is large its generate unknown error so when i increase my volume to 50GB the problem is solved

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use the devel module for that and in `hook_file_presave($file)` you should use `dpm($file)` to test if you get the file object. Try it like this:

```
function MYMODULE_file_presave($file){
  dpm($file);
}
```

If file_presave doesn't work try the `hook_file_insert($file)`.
Both will run if you press the upload button next to the file field or just hit the save button on node edit/add page and will output the file you uploaded to the screen as an object. If you don't have the devel module get it from here: http://drupal.org/project/devel or if you have drush `drush dl devel`. Try to check the server error log or the recent messages in drupal at Reports. You may have a duplicate entry for the file uri in the database. Check if you modify the uploaded files in one of your custom modules. I hope it helps you a bit.

Comment: uploading images from desktop is fine and its upload

Comment: But what if for some reason you don't get the file from your mobile browser? Did you check the database for duplications? The error message you get is really confusing. First it says you have the file but for some reason it can't be uploaded and then it says you did not even touch the photo field. Try it on different mobile browsers.